# SQL Server index recommendations

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have these 3 tables

```
Company (
    Id,
    Name
)

User (
    Id,
    Name,
    CompanyId
)

UserAccess (
    Id,
    UserId,
    Date,
    Type /* 'Login' or 'Logout' */
)
```

The query for the access report is:

```
DECLARE @CompanyId int = 1;

SELECT
    u.Name,
    ua.*
FROM
    UserAccess ua
INNER JOIN 
    User u ON ua.UserId = u.Id
WHERE
    u.CompanyId = @CompanyId
```

The `UserAccess` table can have thousands or millions of rows. So I was thinking of creating a non-clustered index on `UserAccess` table (`UserId`), or is it better to also add `CompanyId` column and reference the index to it? (`Company` table wouldn't be necessary in the query).

What are your recommendations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you should have something like `CREATE INDEX FX_Users ON UserAccess( UserId )` - but you should have that _anyway_: as every FK _should_ have a corresponding `INDEX`, otherwise FK constraint integrity checks will be very, very slow. You should also have `CREATE INDEX FX_Companies ON User ( CompanyId ) INCLUDE ( Name )` as that way the DB engine won't need to read the `User` table rows: they can use just the index.

Comment: I take it `@CompanyId` could have any number of values? I assume this is "non selective" (not many different values in comparison to the row count). Queries against non selective columns can be sped up by a number of means; 1. Filtered indexes; 2. Include with other columns to become a "convering index"; 3. Partition the table by the column

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  u.Name, ua.*
    FROM  UserAccess ua
    INNER JOIN  User u  ON ua.UserId = u.Id
    WHERE  u.CompanyId = @CompanyId
```

The execution will start with `u`, which needs this covering index:

```
INDEX(CompanyId, Id,  Name)
```

Then `ua` needs (preferably clustered)

```
INDEX(UserId)
```